# julia llvmcall failed to parse llvm assembly

Tags: llvm, julia

I am trying to add support for new intrinsics in Julia. For this I use the [llvmcall fork](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/pull/5046). However, when using this in a Julia function, I always encounter the following problem:

declare function:

```
julia> function ptx_test(a,b,c)
       idx = Base.llvmcall("""%1 = tail call i32 @llvm.nvvm.read.ptx.sreg.tid.x() readnone nounwind
                                   ret i32 %1""", Int32, ())
       c[idx] = a[idx] + b[idx]
       return nothing
       end
ptx_test (generic function with 1 method)
```

retrieve llvm IR of this function:

```
julia> code_llvm(ptx_test, (Array{Int32,1},Array{Int32,1},Array{Int32,1}))
PTX function found: ptx_test
ERROR: error compiling ptx_test: Failed to parse LLVM Assembly:
julia: <string>:3:20: error: use of undefined value '@llvm.nvvm.read.ptx.sreg.tid.x'
    %1 = tail call i32 @llvm.nvvm.read.ptx.sreg.tid.x() readnone nounwind
                        ^
in _dump_function at reflection.jl:132
in code_llvm at reflection.jl:139
```

However, if I execute the same code_llvm command again directly after this, It works (correct IR is returned). How can I avoid this error when compiling for the first time?

Comment: Have you enabled PTX support in the Julia LLVM build? Julia does not build with this on by default. The identifier might be implicitly created when you call the first time, which is why it "works" the second time.

Comment: StackOverflow seems like a really weird place for this question. Why wouldn't you ask about this on the pull request for llvmcall instead?

Comment: Hm yes, don't know why I hadn't thought about that :)